# Adding Click Event to Dynamically added List Items without Jquery

Tags: javascript

my problem is when i click on the provider which is a list-item with some elements like img and h2 i always get the last value of the provider variable. the parameter which i assign to clickProvider did not contain the value which it gets when i iterate through all providers.

when i click on the list-item it did not contains the right text.

i hope that you can understand my problem.

```
function clickProvider(id) {
    console.log(id);
}

function loadProviders() {
    empty('provider-list');

    var providerList = elementById('provider-list');

    for (var index in providers) {
        var provider = providers[index];

        if (elementByName(provider.categorie).length > 0) {
            addProviderToCategory(provider.categorie, provider.text).addEventListener('click', function () {
                clickProvider(provider.text);
                return false;
            });
        } else {
            addProviderCategory(provider.categorie)
            addProviderToCategory(provider.categorie, provider.text).addEventListener('click', function () {
                clickProvider(provider.text);
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('DOM loaded');

    loadProviders();
})
```

**Edit:**

HTML Code.
The for-loop above creates that HTML.

```
<ul id="provider-list">
    <li name="category1">
        <a href="">Category Header 1</a>
        <ul id="category1">
            <li>
                <img src="">
                <a href="">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="">
                <a href="">Item 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li name="category2">
        <a href="">Category Header 2</a>
        <ul id="category2">
            <li>
                <img src="">
                <a href="">Item 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Would be better if you post your html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special scope inside a `for` loop, so the variable `provider` is overwritten on every iteration, and by the time you click an element, you have the last iterated `provider`.

What you need is some kind of closure or scope to keep the value of `provider`, like this

```
function loadProviders() {
    empty('provider-list');

    var providerList = elementById('provider-list');

    for (var index in providers) {
        (function(provider) {
            if (elementByName(provider.categorie).length > 0) {
                addProviderToCategory(provider.categorie, provider.text).addEventListener('click', function () {
                    clickProvider(provider.text);
                    return false;
                });
            } else {
                addProviderCategory(provider.categorie)
                addProviderToCategory(provider.categorie, provider.text).addEventListener('click', function () {
                    clickProvider(provider.text);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        })(providers[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: elementById() is just a helper function. it returns the html element. elementById contains return document.getElementById(id);

Comment: Oh, that's `providerList`, I misread that, I was talking about `providers`, and that should be an object, not an array

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
    var navigation = document.getElementById("provider-list");
    navigation.onclick = function (evt) {
        // Event tweaks, since IE wants to go its own way...
        var event = evt || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var text = "Link's text: " + target.innerHTML;
        alert(text);
    }
};
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/wvgefuz3/1/)